# Save before running tests? (Prepend function?)

Tags: advice, compilation, saving, nadvice

How can I prepend a function call in Elisp?

E.g. I have a key binding (`C-c C-c C-t`) that runs some tests (command `rustic-cargo-test`) and it always asks me if I want to save - I'd like to run `(save-some-buffers 'no-prompt)` each time before this, so it doesn't ask.

With the standard `recompile` function I created my own function and rebound the key, e.g.:

```
(defun save-and-recompile ()
  (interactive)
  (save-some-buffers 'no-prompt)
  (recompile))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-k") 'save-and-recompile)
```

But this feels a bit hacky, and I would want to do it for other `rustic-cargo-*` functions. Is there a better way than writing a function/macro to automate the above? (Probably putting it in the `rustic-hook` and not making it global though!)

Answer (score 0):

Do you *always* want `recompile` to do what you describe? If so, you can *advise* that function, giving it `:before` advice:

```lisp
 (advice-add 'recompile :before (lambda () (save-some-buffers 'no-prompt)))
```

See the Elisp manual, node [Advising Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html).

If you don't want `recompile` to always do that then I think defining your own command, as you did, is a good approach.

But I don't really understand the relation between your `rustic-cargo-*` commands/functions and `recompile`. It sounds like you might really want to advise some of those `rustic-cargo-*` functions.

Comment: The `rustic-cargo-*` functions all end with a call to `rustic-compilation` but before they do that they call `rustic-compilation-process-live` which, in turn, calls `rustic-save-some-buffers`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `rustic-save-some-buffers` looks at `compilation-ask-about-save` so

```
(setq compilation-ask-about-save nil)
```

may help.